# Python Django mysqldb select with unicode value

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

When I use this clause, everything is right. `find` in here is `モンキー・D・ルフィ`

```
   sql_fmt = "select name, gender, age, height, hobby, ability, popularity, voice_actor, birth_place, image from characters where name in ('%s');" % find.encode('utf-8')
   self.db.execute(sql_fmt)
```

But when I use this clause, error happened. `find` in here is `(モンキー・D・ルフィ)` or `('モンキー・D・ルフィ')`

```
sql_fmt = "select name, gender, age, height, hobby, ability, popularity, voice_actor, birth_place, image from characters where name in %s;"
self.db.execute(sql_fmt, find)
```

**Error**:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(\'\xe3\x83\xa2\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x83\xbbD\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\xab\xe3\x83\x95\xe3\x82\xa3\')'' at line 1")
>   And for this clause, error happened. `find` here is `モンキー・D・ルフィ`.

```
sql_fmt = "select name, gender, age, height, hobby, ability, popularity, voice_actor, birth_place, image from characters where name in ('%s');"
self.db.execute(sql_fmt, find)
```

And for this clause, everything goes well. `find` here is `モンキー・D・ルフィ`.

```
sql_fmt = "select name, gender, age, height, hobby, ability, popularity, voice_actor, birth_place, image from characters where name in (%s);"
self.db.execute(sql_fmt, find)
```

**Note :**

I use `in` means it is a set of strings, but not just a single string.

Comment: miss "" around String ~> much be " some text "

Comment: @NamNguyễn You mean change `(モンキー・D・ルフィ)` to `("モンキー・D・ルフィ")`?

Comment: have you try to find.encode('utf-8')?

Comment: @Tiny.D I have tried, same error.

Comment: your find here is string like `"(モンキー・D・ルフィ) or ('モンキー・D・ルフィ')"`?

Comment: @Tiny.D No,`(モンキー・D・ルフィ)`  or `('モンキー・D・ルフィ')`, I have tried these two. More info added.

Comment: Why on earth are you running these type of queries with django? Why are you not using the ORM?

Answer (score 0):

May be you missing "" in the query

```
# it should be: 
select * from characters where name = "some string"
#OR 
select * from characters where name in "some string"
# In your case:
sql_fmt = "select name, gender, age, height, hobby, ability, popularity, voice_actor, birth_place, image from characters where name in "%s";"
```

Or may be some kind of this, i don't use it.

You should use:

```
res = Models.Objects.filter(name__in = yourlist)
# Django help you all the way to convert it to Query
```

Comment: I use `in` which means it is a set of strings, not a single string.

Comment: i recomment you to use Django querry (not RAW querry). And if not, i am sure you are not asking about django-query... remove the django's tag

Comment: tag has been removed.

Comment: Need parentheses when using `IN`.